# Storybook style and change location of "Show code" "Hide code" button

Tags: css, storybook

I've been searchigng the docs and haven't been able to find any relevant information on how and if it's even possible to change the location of the "show code" "hide code" button in the storybook styling.
I want to style it and move it from the right bottom to the left bottom.

[image: show code with arrow pointing right to left]
[image: hide code with arrow pointing right to left]